# Highlight text with a short right margin in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to put highlights around text, with a lefthand and righthand margin on the highlight. So the result would be:

[image: proper highlight]

It would not be:

[image: wrong highlight]

Here is what i have so far:

```css
ol.number {
  list-style-type: none;
} 

ol.number {
  counter-reset: number;
  background-color:#FFFF00;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

ol.number > li:before {
  content: "(" counter(number, decimal) ") ";
  counter-increment: number;
}
```

```html
<ol class="number">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>quadrillion</li>
</ol>
```

Any idea to fix this?

Comment: you can use `padding-left` and `padding-right` instead for `margin`

Comment: `Padding` is the space that's inside the element between the element and the border.` Padding` goes around all four sides of the content and you can target and change the padding for each side with CSS. `Margin` is the space between the border and next element

Comment: `padding-right` and `margin-right` affect the text, but not the highlight

Comment: I added the `html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the `ol` tag a display of inline-block. Then give it padding to the left and right:

```css
ol.number {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: number;
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  padding: 0 8em 0 2.5em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}

ol.number>li:before {
  content: "(" counter(number, decimal) ") ";
  counter-increment: number;
}
```

```html
<ol class="number">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>quadrillion</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: When it's an `inline-block` the text is displayed on one line, not two.

Comment: @rachelvsamuel set the `ol` tag only, not the `li` tags. Click "Run code snippet" to see

Answer (score 0):

Use this for example:

```
<div style="100px"><p><span style="background:yellow;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px">one</span></p></div>
```

You can change the size of the div so it fits your needs.

Comment: How do I use this code on an `<ol>` list. It works when I put `span` inside the `<li>`'s but that's awfully messy.